# how to remove duplicate from UNION Query result?

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables :

Table1

```
id | name | tech
-----------------
1  | jose | python
2  | rolf | java
3  | alain| scala
```

Table2

```
id | name | tech
-----------------
4  | jose | haskell
5  | rolf | c++
6  | sylvie|js
```

I want to merge them with a UNION and get the name only from the first table
so the result should be like that:

```
id | name | tech
-----------------
1  | jose | python
2  | rolf | java
3  | alain| scala
4  | sylvie|js
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `WHERE` clause.

```
select id, name, tech from table1
union all
select id, name, tech from table2 where name not in (select name from table1);
```